# Definition of pronilpotent Lie algebra

Tags: definition, lie-algebras

I have a doubt about the following definition of pronilpotent differential graded Lie algebra found e.g. in [Willwacher (Def. 2.21)](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~wilthoma/docs/grt.pdf) and [Lazarev-Markl (Def. 7.1)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.1037v2.pdf):

> **Definition:** A *pronilpotent* (or: *complete* in Lazarev-Markl) differential graded Lie algebra is an inverse limit of finite dimensional nilpotent differential graded Lie algebras.

Does anyone know if we are allowed any limit, or can we take only sequential limits indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e.
$$\mathfrak{g}:=\varprojlim_n \mathfrak{g}_n\longrightarrow\ldots\longrightarrow\mathfrak{g}_{n+1}\longrightarrow\mathfrak{g}_n\longrightarrow\ldots,$$
or still something else?

Comment: You're melting two things. A pronilpotent dgla is a projective limit of **nilpotent** finite-dimensional dgla. You can replace dgla twice by "Lie algebra", but not just once. Also "nilpotent" is missing once from your sentence.

Comment: And yes this allows any limits, e.g., an uncountable (unrestricted) direct product of finite-dimensional Lie algebras cannot be written as such a projective limit w.r. to a sequence.

Comment: @YCor Thanks for the corrections and the answer! (I always work over chain complexes, the dg just slipped...)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your correction. First, for a finite-dimensional Lie algebra, pronilpotent just means nilpotent. Second, an inverse limit of finite-dimensional nilpotent Lie algebras is by definition a pronilpotent Lie algebra (not a pronilpotent DGLA).

Comment: @YCor Ah, thanks. Typo again. Oups!

Comment: But you still melt half of Lie algebras, half of DGLA. In Lazarev-Markl they define a **complete DGLA** as an inverse limit of **finite-dimensional nilpotent DGLAs**.

Comment: @YCor I know, everything here is dg. I'm sorry if it was not clear. I will edit my post and add "differential graded" in front of everything.

Comment: OK. To add to the answer: the projective limit comes with a topology (Tychonov topology). I think that it is metrizable if and only if the projective limit can be described by a sequence.

Comment: @YCor Thanks. Is it the one induced by the filtration by increasing numbers of brackets?

Comment: Not necessarily, for instance when the pronilpotent algebra is actually nilpotent (e.g., an infinite countable product of a fixed algebra). However, it's probably true when it is assume that the abelianization is finite-dimensional.